# SQL Server - SELECT TOP 5 rows for each FK

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I've got the following query, that looks up the TOP 5 *Products* matching the search. Each *Product* is associated with a *Shop*

> SELECT     TOP 5 * FROM     Products
>   p, Shops s WHERE    p.ShopId =
>   s.ShopId AND    p.ProductName LIKE
>   '%christmas%'

I need to extend this so that it returns me the TOP 5 *Products* in **each** *Shop*.

Could anyone let me know how the query could be modified to achieve this? - i.e. choose the TOP 5 products matching "%christmas%" in *each* shop (rather than the current which shows the TOP 5 products matching "%chrismas%" across *all* shops).

Comment: What db please: MySQL, SQL Server etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're actually missing an ORDER BY to make the TOP meaningful, or any solution based on ROW_NUMBER which requires an ORDER BY.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Shops s 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 5
        *
    FROM
        Products p
    WHERE
        p.ShopId = s.ShopId AND p.ProductName LIKE '%christmas%'
    ORDER BY --added on edit
        ???
) X
```

Comment: the actual query use a FTE to do a full text search - ordered by Rank (CONTAINSTABLE) - took that out of the example here for clarity :-)

Comment: keep in mind that you need to add an alias for the query of top 5 in order for it to work. e.g. CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 5...) AS p

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select * from (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by s.ShopId order by p.ProductName)
    from Products p, Shops s 
    where p.ShopId = s.ShopId AND p.ProductName LIKE '%christmas%'
) a where a.rn <= 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great solution I just found.

Select the TOP n Rows For Each Group
Arnie Rowland, March 13, 2008

There are Multiple Rows for Each Category, and there is a desire to
SELECT ONLY the TOP two (2) Rows per Category by Price.
For example, from the following data:

```
RowID    Category    ID  Description     Price
1    Pot     A1  Small Saucepan  21.50
2    Pot     A2  1 Qt Saucepan   29.95
3    Pot     A3  1.5 Qt Saucepan     33.95
4    Pot     A4  Double Boiler   39.50
5    Pot     A5  Stewpot     49.50
6    Pot     A6  Pressure Cooker     79.95
7    Pan     B1  8" Pie  6.95
8    Pan     B2  8" Sq Cake  7.50
9    Pan     B3  Bundt Cake  12.50
10   Pan     B4  9x12 Brownie    7.95
11   Bowl    C1  Lg Mixing   27.50
12   Bowl    C2  Sm Mixing   17.50
13   Tools   T1  14" Spatula     9.95
```

The desired output is:

```
RowID    Category    ID  Description     Price
11   Bowl    C1  Lg Mixing   27.50
12   Bowl    C2  Sm Mixing   17.50
9    Pan     B3  Bundt Cake  12.50
10   Pan     B4  9x12 Brownie    7.95
6    Pot     A6  Pressure Cooker     79.95
5    Pot     A5  Stewpot     49.50
13   Tools   T1  14" Spatula     9.95
```

There are several methods to accomplish the desired output. 
This demonstration provides a Solution for SQL Server 2005 / SQL Server 2008 , 
and then a Solution for SQL Server 2000.

Create Sample Data for Both Solutions

```
-- Suppress data loading messages
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Create Sample Data using a Table Varable
DECLARE @MyTable table
   (  RowID         int   IDENTITY, 
      Category      varchar(5),
      [ID]          varchar(5),
      [Description] varchar(25),
      Price         decimal(10,2)
   )

-- Load Sample Data

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A1', 'Small Saucepan', 21.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A2', '1 Qt Saucepan', 29.95 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A3', '1.5 Qt Saucepan', 33.95 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A4', 'Double Boiler', 39.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A5', 'Stewpot', 49.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A6', 'Pressure Cooker', 79.95 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pan', 'B1', '8"" Pie', 6.95 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pan', 'B2', '8"" Sq Cake', 7.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pan', 'B3', 'Bundt Cake', 12.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pan', 'B4', '9x12 Brownie', 7.95 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Bowl', 'C1', 'Lg Mixing', 27.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Bowl', 'C2', 'Sm Mixing', 17.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Tools', 'T1', '14"" Spatula', 9.95 )
Return to Top
```

SQL Server 2005 / SQL Server 2008 Solution

```
--Query to Retrieve Desired Data
SELECT
   RowID,
   Category,
   [ID],
   [Description],
   Price
FROM (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Price DESC ) AS 'RowNumber',
         RowID,
         Category,
         [ID],
         [Description],
         Price
      FROM @MyTable
      ) dt
WHERE RowNumber <= 2

-- Results
RowID Category  ID Description     Price
11    Bowl      C1 Lg Mixing       27.50
12    Bowl      C2 Sm Mixing       17.50
9     Pan       B3 Bundt Cake      12.50
10    Pan       B4 9x12 Brownie    7.95
6     Pot       A6 Pressure Cooker 79.95
5     Pot       A5 Stewpot         49.50
13    Tools     T1 14" Spatula     9.95
Return to Top
```

SQL Server 2005 / SQL Server 2008 Solution using a CTE
(Added by: Jacob Sebastian)

```
-- Define a CTE with the name "dt" 
;WITH dt AS (
     SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Price DESC ) AS 'RowNumber',
         RowID,
         Category,
         [ID],
         [Description],
         Price
      FROM @MyTable
)
-- and select the data from the CTE
SELECT
   RowID,
   Category,
   [ID],
   [Description],
   Price
FROM dt
WHERE RowNumber <= 2

-- Results
RowID Category  ID Description     Price
11    Bowl      C1 Lg Mixing       27.50
12    Bowl      C2 Sm Mixing       17.50
9     Pan       B3 Bundt Cake      12.50
10    Pan       B4 9x12 Brownie    7.95
6     Pot       A6 Pressure Cooker 79.95
5     Pot       A5 Stewpot         49.50
13    Tools     T1 14" Spatula     9.95
Return to Top
```

SQL 2000 Solution

```
--Query to Retrieve Desired Data
SELECT DISTINCT
   RowID,
   Category,
   [ID],
   [Description],
   Price
FROM @MyTable t1
WHERE RowID IN (SELECT TOP 2
                   RowID
                FROM @MyTable t2
                WHERE t2.Category = t1.Category
                ORDER BY Price DESC
               )
ORDER BY 
   Category,
   Price DESC

-- Results
RowID Category  ID Description     Price
11    Bowl      C1 Lg Mixing       27.50
12    Bowl      C2 Sm Mixing       17.50
9     Pan       B3 Bundt Cake      12.50
10    Pan       B4 9x12 Brownie    7.95
6     Pot       A6 Pressure Cooker 79.95
5     Pot       A5 Stewpot         49.50
13    Tools     T1 14" Spatula     9.95
```

From: [Select the TOP n Rows For Each Group](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SelectTopNByGroup)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        A.Product_Group_code
        ,B.Sub_Product_Group_code
        ,A.Product_code
        ,A.Product_name
FROM dbo.A A
    LEFT JOIN dbo.B B
        ON A.Product_code = B.Product_code
WHERE  B.Product_code IN
                (
                    SELECT TOP 5 E.Product_code
                    FROM dbo.A D
                        LEFT JOIN dbo.B E
                            ON D.Product_code = E.Product_code
                    WHERE E.Sub_Product_Group_code = B.Sub_Product_Group_code
                )
        AND B.Sub_Product_Group_code IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY B.Sub_Product_Group_code,A.Product_name
```